# Unsupervised clustering of words in R without knowing k

Tags: r, string, nlp, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

As a beginner in NLP, I am trying to find the best way to cluster single words with unsupervised clustering, specifically where the number of clusters `k` is not known in advance.   I have a group of words that contains clusters of words are very similar to each other (off by one or two letters) - by this I mean cosine similarity (not semantic) -   I would like to be able to find the number of these clusters in the group without defining `k` in advance.

To take a basic example, I have tried using Levenshtein Distance, which takes the argument `k` in advance:

```
#Levenshtein Distance

str = c('foo', 'food', 'fo', 'ten', 'zen')
d  <- adist(str)
rownames(d) <- str
hc <- hclust(as.dist(d))
plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc,k=2)
```

The algorithm performs well, but `k` is necessary to know.

[image]

Is there a good algorithm for clustering words?  Most of the documentation I've come across uses td-idf and pairwise distances in sentences, but this is a much simpler problem and nothing really addresses just clustering groups of single words without knowing `k`.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you found anything that you'd recommend?